# Target Platform and 'Could not load file or assembly' error

Tags: asp.net, winforms, assemblies, target-platform

I have a Win Forms application that targets 64 bit platform (it is required as it uses the 64-bit `Oracle.DataAccess` libraries).

I've added an ASP.net forms application to this solution, and I would like to add a reference to the WinForms app to the ASP.net app.

My WebApp also targets 64 bit and builds correctly, but when I run it I get:

> 'Could not load file or assembly '`Oracle.DataAccess`' or one of its dependencies'.

I also made sure that the Oracle.DataAccess are the new 64-bit version.
Any ideas?
The Winforms application (that has the reference to Oracle.DataAccess) are running 100%, so that tells me the problem might not be with the dll version.

More info on the error below:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = Domain\myUser
LOG: DisplayName = Oracle.DataAccess
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: Oracle.DataAccess | Domain ID: 3
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/xx/UDWIntegration/UDWWeb/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = D:\xx\UDWWeb\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\xx\UDWWeb\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\xx\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/ef51aef3/7f23a77a/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/ef51aef3/7f23a77a/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/xx/UDWWeb/bin/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.

Stack Trace: 


[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +16
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +752
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +218
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
   System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler..ctor(VirtualDirectory vdir) +124
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectoryInternal(VirtualDirectory vdir, Boolean ignoreErrors) +44
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectory(VirtualDirectory vdir, VirtualPath virtualDir, Boolean ignoreErrors) +187
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +74
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +299
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +103
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound) +165
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp) +43
   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +31
   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String virtualPath, String path) +37
   System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +346
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Have you checked the references on the Oracle.DataAccess dll? Maybe your application tries to load it from another place where only the x86 version is present. Also, please confirm that for all projects the project properties -> build -> platform target is x64 when the build platform is set to x64.

Comment: Check the Target Framework in the project properties for both apps and make sure they match.  WinForms by default will target ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" instead of ".NET Framework 4"

Comment: I double checked both projects to be on x64.  I redownloaded the Oracle.DataAccess 64 bit dll's, and made sure I referenced that.

Comment: Have you put a copy of the Oracle.DataAccess dll in your project's bin folder? That is where it is trying to load it from. Visual Studio will not copy the dll from the referenced location to the bin folder for you. You have to do it manually.

Comment: Yes, I did this as well - thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config

Your trace clearly shows that your code is running in 32-bit mode.  A 64-bit program loads the machine.config file from the c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64 directory.  So the BadImageFormatException is entirely expected.

It is not up to your project to configure in what mode it runs, it is the app-pool configuration in IIS that selects the bitness.  Use the Advanced Settings as shown in [this web page](https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/KB/a1114/how-to-enable-32-bit-application-pool-iis-7-dedicatedvps.aspx) to configure it.  Do make sure you talk to whomever normally configures the machine, this setting change is not an accident.

Comment: Thanks - is it possible to change this setting on my dev machine during design time (i.e. not deployed on IIS yet)?

Comment: First google hit: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3254745-allow-for-iis-express-64-bit-to-run-from-visual-st

Comment: I saw that one as well, but the fact that it states that it is not fully tested made me worry.  I did try this, but still no success.  I also tried a deployment on IIS with 32-bit enabled, but still this error.  However, I think that something did work as the error message are looking a bit different.  I will accept as answer due to this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you're having this issue while running/debugging a web app in Visual Studio (VS) using IIS Express make sure the following setting is checked:

Tools>Options>Projects & Solutions>Web Projects>Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by download and execute the install.bat file in 'ODAC112030Xcopy.zip' from [64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html).